# Materialize CSS - waves-effect blurs form

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

I'm exploring the Materialize CSS library, and I'm having some issues with the waves effect class.
When added to a button it blurs the form it is in.

This is the form without the waves-effect:
[image: form without waves-effect]

After adding the waves-effect it gets blurry:

[image: form with waves-effect - blurry]

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="login-form centered">
<h1><i class="fa fa-user menu-icon"></i> Login</h1>
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           ng-model="alc.user.username"
           id="username"
           placeholder="Username"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password"
           class="form-control"
           id="password"
           ng-model="alc.user.password"
           placeholder="Password"/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit"
          class="waves-effect btn"
          ng-click="alc.login(alc.user.username)">Sign in
  </button>
  <button type="submit"
          class="waves-effect btn"
          ng-click="alc.register()">Register
  </button>
</form>
</div>
```

When checking the css attributes inherited from the class, I noticed that what's causing the blur is: `will-change: opacity, transform;`

After removing it the text returned to normal.

So my question is, why is this happening? 
and how to apply the effect without the side effect?

**Edit:**
I've checked in chrome firefox and explorer, and the issue only occurs on chrome.

Comment: Which browsers have you tested?

Comment: Chrome. now the you mentioned it I checked in firefox & explorer as well and the issue only occurs in chrome. I'll edit the post and mention that detail.

Comment: Are you using any other frameworks besides Materiallize? I made a small fiddle and it renders and works correctly across Chrome and Firefox (I'm on Mac so can't currently verify IE). https://jsfiddle.net/tz32qme6/

Comment: I'm using: Bootstrap, Font-awsome and Animates.css. I excluded all of them to check if the cause is a colission with one of them, but the blur remains.

Comment: Ok, I've found the culprit. I had the following css on the form: transform :translate(-50%, -50%) ; I used it to center the the form.. apparently it doesn't play well with the attributes of the waves-effect class.